# How can a team of users share a large monitor?

Tags: external-display

Okay folks...I know this is a bit dorky but...I work in an engineering group and it would sometimes be nice to have a large monitor that everybody can project their screen onto - much like NCIS when what they instantly project their workstation screen on a large screen.

I know how do have a duplicate monitor using a video card. I also understand and use TeamViewer, GoToMeeting and other screen sharing applications. Not what I am talking about here. Does anybody know of a way that I could have a single large, wall mounted monitor that any workstation in a group could "cast" they screen to?

Answer (score 0):

There are devices called "Screen Splitter" or "Multiviewer" where you can display up to four sources to one monitor.

Here are some examples of these products:

- [NTI - 4K HDMI Quad Screen Splitter/Multiviewer](http://www.networktechinc.com/4k-hdmi-multiviewer.html)
- [KVM - HDMI Multiviewer Quad Screen with real time viewing and seamless switching](http://www.kvmswitchtech.com/hdmi-multiviewer-quad-screen-with-real-time-viewing-and-seamless-switching-p50806.htm)

I hope this helps